# Mapping dictionary with rows values

Tags: python, mapping, ordereddictionary

My problem is how to map dictionary values to row indices. I have a dictionary like:

```
ordered_dict = OrderedDict(1:"id", 2:"name", 3:"address", 4:"salary")
```

And I got rows from a `select` query like:

```
row = ["David", 4500, "France", 121]
```

With the following code, where i get `id` as first index in dictionary, which is fourth in case of `row`, I want to map them such that variable value will actually get the values from the `id` of the `row`.

```
for item in ordered_dict.iteritems:
    value = row[index of current item in dictionary] # which is 1 for the id.
```

But I want the index of `id` in a `row`. ie.

```
value = row[index of id in row]  # that is, value = row [4]
```

so that i can retrieve the value of `id` from `row`, which is `121`.

I can not break the current structure of the dictionary or the `select` query, so I am looking for a way to map the row items to the dictionary.

Edit: In the above code what I get in the first iteration is

```
  value = row[0] # here 0 is the id of dictionary,
```

But if `row[0]` will retrieve `"David"` as index `0` of `row` contains `"David"`, I want the index of `id` to be mapped with `row`, which is `3` in my example, so that I will get `value = row[3]`, here `3` is index of `id` in `row`, and hence I will get `121` as the result.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Could you please provide the expected output?

Comment: could you post your query for retrieving data? you can make the desired order when selecting columns in query so that it can map with dictionary

Comment: I have edited my post with expected output.

Comment: @Aamir Adnan: the problem is I cannot change the structure of the exisiting select query.

Answer (score 3):

This should do the work:

```
results = cursor.fetchall()
col_names = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]
rows_dict = map(lambda row: dict(zip(col_names, row)), results)
```

It's working for PostgreSQL and SQLite3, but I haven't tested it with MySQL. If for postgres IndexError or something like this occurs, try changing second line on:

```
col_names = [column.name for column in cursor.description]
```